# Does grunt-contrib-uglify not parse "let" keywords?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am getting an error,

> 'Unexpected token: name (bazz)'

when my grunt task is running uglify. 
The only thing I noticed on that line was that I was using the 'let' keyword instead of 'var', so I wasn't sure why that error was getting thrown.

I have an if else statement with let varName in each, i.e.:

```
function foo (bar) {
    if (condition) {
        let bazz = fn();
        //doSomething with bazz
        _.assign(bar, bazz);
    } else {
        let bazz = fn2();
        //doSomething different with bazz
        _.assign(bar, bazz);
    }
}
```

I could alter it by having a `var bazz = {};` before the if else clause, but I wanted to avoid that because I'd have to assign bazz to fn() and fn2() regardless.

Wanted to know if anybody else has run into this and what they did to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I encountered a similar problem with gulp-uglify. It threw an error `Unexpected token name «i», expected punc «;»` when it encountered a `let` keyword in a for loop declaration. `for (let i = ca.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)`. Changing `let` to `var` seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After researching this topic a little bit more I found out that grunt-contrib-uglify and also gulp-uglify has UglifyJS as a dependency and it does not support ES6 "Harmony" yet. Follow https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448 for updates.

You can also use tools like [grunt-babel](https://github.com/babel/grunt-babel) to compile your ES6 code to ES5.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the following on the official [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) npm page.

Note the recommendation:

> To help properly handle error conditions with Node streams, this
>   project recommends the use of [pump](https://github.com/mafintosh/pump). For more information, see [Why Use
>   Pump?](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/docs/why-use-pump/README.md#why-use-pump).

My implementation of the example on the above page is:

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var pump = require('pump');  

// the npm page states:  
// can be a git checkout or another module 
// (such as `uglify-js-harmony` for ES6 support)
var uglifyjs = require('uglify-js-harmony');   
var minifier = require('gulp-uglify/minifier');  

var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('compress', function (cb) {  
  // the 'options' argument is included in the example, 
  // but i don't know what it does or how it can be removed  
  var options = {  
    preserveComments: 'license'  
  };  

  pump([  
      gulp.src('my_scripts/*.js'),  // gets all js scripts in this folder  
      minifier(options, uglifyjs),  
      concat('my_bundled_script.js'), // concatenates all scripts into this file  
      gulp.dest('dist')  // puts the file into this folder
    ],cb 
  );  
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "latest",
    "pump": "latest",
    "gulp-concat": "latest",
    "gulp-uglify": "latest",
    "uglify-js-harmony": "latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

**Results**

Without using `uglify-js-harmony`:

- `pump` was helpful in locating where the error came from (when using `gulp-uglify`)
- a file that had a `let` statement caused errors

When using `uglify-js-harmony`, the errors did not occur.

**Other considerations:**

The above page currently shows:

```
// can be a git checkout or another module  
// (such as `uglify-js-harmony` for ES6 support)
var uglifyjs = require('uglify-js');
```

But when installing `uglify-js-harmony` I got the warning message:

> npm WARN deprecated uglify-js-harmony@2.7.7: deprecated in favour of
>   uglify-es

When I tried to use `uglify-es` instead of `uglify-js-harmony` , however, I got an error message, similar to that documented here:

https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/287

I tried to follow the issue thread from there but got lost and couldn't find a definitive solution of how to implement `uglify-es`.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.